# Understanding instruments data

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, instruments

I'm profiling my app and trying to understand the collected data. The action that I perform is uploading photos from camera roll to my server(5-8 photos).

I wonder how to deal with such kind of leaks:

[image]

The stack trace looks useless and the class that leaks is not my custom class.

Also I have such a weird output:

[image]

Is it at all possible??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial helped me getting started with instruments:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started

Check the paragraph "Allocations, Allocations, Allocations" to get better understanding about the Allocations instrument.

Comment: Well, not as much info as I want. Though, I got answers for some of my questions, thanks.